# Can you trigger (firebase) cloud functions on auth login (but not account creation)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

It seems like the firebase auth triggers are onCreate and onDelete. I'd like to also fire some kind of trigger on non-create login (basically periodically syncing the user's avatar and display name and such with what's in the database).

I can fake this by just doing it on the client side, which is what i'm doing right now - just updating the user record with whatever is in firebase.auth.user. Excitingly, this can't be done right after login, since if the login is also account creation, the user record tends to not exist (since it is created via a triggered cloud function), and I can't tell from auth.signInWithPopup() if the resultant signin was a creation or login event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such trigger.  As you've observed, it just provides onCreate and onDelete.

Firebase Auth doesn't provide a way to sync the user's avatar with their authentication provider.  It just copies the URL once at the time the account was created.

If you need to update the user's profile picture, you will have to do that yourself by calling `updateProfile()` on the user object and provide a URL for the picture.